Redirecting Azure TTS audio to a virtual cable in Python 3.9
What I'm trying to is :
Azure SST -> Azure TTS -> Sending audio through a virtual cable for Discord
I have the virtual cable installed and everything, but I'm clueless about how to send correctly the audio through the virtual cable.
I've tried to change the audio default output in Windows, and it worked but this solution is kinda messy since many software and video games will go through the virtual cable.
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config="I don't know what to put here")
I would guess that I can change the audio output device in audio_config, but I don't know what it accepts. The documentation mentions that it's for changing the audio output device, but no information on what exactly it wants.
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

load_dotenv

while 0==0:
    def recognize_from_microphone():
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.getenv('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.getenv('SPEECH_REGION'))
        speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"
        speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "en-US-JaneNeural"

        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

        print("Speak into your microphone.")
        speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
        tts(str(speech_recognition_result.text))

    def tts(text):
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.getenv('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.getenv('SPEECH_REGION'))
        speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "en-US-JaneNeural"
        speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config="I don't know what to put here")

        speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
    
    recognize_from_microphone()


Sorry for the messy loop, I will try something more clean later
Thanks for helping!

I tried the following code to convert speech to text using audio through a virtual cable in Python 3.9.
Install the VB-Audio Virtual Cable and set up the virtual cable as the default audio output device in your system settings.
Code :
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
 
load_dotenv()
 
def recognize_from_microphone():
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.getenv('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.getenv('SPEECH_REGION'))
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"
 
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
 
    print("Speak into your microphone.")
    speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
 
    if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        recognized_text = speech_recognition_result.text
        print("Recognized:", recognized_text)
        tts(str(recognized_text))
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        print("No speech could be recognized")
    elif speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = speech_recognition_result.cancellation_details
        print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
 
def tts(text):
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.getenv('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.getenv('SPEECH_REGION'))
    speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "en-US-JaneNeural"
 
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(filename='CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)')
    speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
 
    result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text(text)
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
        print("Speech synthesized successfully")
    else:
        print("Speech synthesis failed: {}".format(result.error_details))
 
recognize_from_microphone()

.env :
SPEECH_KEY='<speech_key>'
SPEECH_REGION='<speech_region>'

Output :
It ran successfully and produced the text output with input speech as shown below.

C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\kamali2>python sample.py  
Speak into your microphone.  
Recognized: Hello Kamali, how are you?
Speech synthesized successfully

